# Javascript I can't reach result variables in function

Tags: javascript, function, public

I called my datas with ajax then created variables in result but I cannot reach my variables in other function. How can I reach variables or create as a public function ? $("#btBilgileriAktar") is my new function .I want to take variables in this function.

Thank you for your helps.

```js
$.ajax({

      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        data: gripin
      },
      datatype: 'html',
      url: '<?php echo site_url('
      servis / bring_Cari '); ?>',
      success: function(result) {

        var obj = $.parseJSON(result);

        // console.log(obj);

        $.each(obj, function(key, value) {


          // console.log(value);
          $("table#cariler tbody").append("<tr class=\"cariKayit\"><td class=\"tdCariAdi\">" + obj[key].CARI_ISIM + "</td><td class=\"tdVergiNo\">" + ((obj[key].VERGI_NUMARASI == null) ? "" : obj[key].VERGI_NUMARASI) + "</td><td class=\"tdVergiDairesi\">" + ((obj[key].VERGI_DAIRESI == null) ? "" : obj[key].VERGI_DAIRESI) + "</td><td class=\"tdCariAdres\">" + ((obj[key].CARI_ADRES == null) ? "" : obj[key].CARI_ADRES) + "</td><td class=\"tdCariTel\">" + ((obj[key].CARI_TEL == null) ? "" : obj[key].CARI_TEL) + "</td><td class=\"tdCariIlce\">" + ((obj[key].CARI_ILCE == null) ? "" : obj[key].CARI_ILCE) + "</td><td class=\"tdCariIl\">" + ((obj[key].CARI_IL == null) ? "" : obj[key].CARI_IL) + "</td><td><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"checks\"/></td></tr>");


        });
        $('#checks').on("click", function() { //Çalışıyor
          var nAdi = $(this).parent().parent().find(".tdCariAdi").text();
          var nVno = $(this).parent().parent().find(".tdVergiNo").text();
          var nVdairesi = $(this).parent().parent().find(".tdVergiDairesi").text();
          var nAdres = $(this).parent().parent().find(".tdCariAdres").text();
          var nTel = $(this).parent().parent().find(".tdCariTel").text();
          var nIlce = $(this).parent().parent().find(".tdCariIlce").text();
          var nIl = $(this).parent().parent().find(".tdCariIl").text();

       
        });


        $('#btBilgileriAktar').on('click', function() { //Buda seçimi çekiyor ama burada sıkıntı var verileri almıyor.
          var tcLength = nVno.toString();
          if (tcLength.length == 11) {

            $("#spTc").val(tcLength);

          } else if (tcLength.length == 10) {

            $("#spVno").val(tcLength);

          } else {

            $("#spTc").val("");
            $("#spVno").val("");
          }
          $("#spCariAdi").val(nAdi);
          $("#spVergiDairesi").val(nVdairesi);
          $("#spAdres").val(nAdres);
          $("#spTel").val(nTel);
          $("#spIlce").val(nIlce);
          $("#spIl").val(nIl);
        });


      }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="musteri">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Müşteri Adı</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="spCariAdi" type="text" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Adres</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="spAdres" type="text" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">İlçe</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="spIlce" type="text" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">İl</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="spIl" type="text" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Tel</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="spTel" type="text" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Vergi Dairesi</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="spVergiDairesi" type="text" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">TC Kimlik No</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="spTc" type="text" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Vergi No</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="spVno" type="text" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are declaring variables in another function. You need global variables for accessing them from different function.

```
 var nAdi = ''; //global var declaration

 $('#checks').on("click", function() { //Çalışıyor
      nAdi = $(this).parent().parent().find(".tdCariAdi").text(); //assigning value
 });

 $('#btBilgileriAktar').on('click', function() {
     $("#spCariAdi").val(nAdi); // retrieving value
 });
```

Comment: I can reach now.I used variable as a global .Thank you for your help.